# How to access fastOpt.js?

Tags: javascript, scala.js

I have the `web-fastopt.js` file compiled in the JVM project of a **Cross Project**.

```
[info] Fast optimizing .../main/web/jvm/target/scala-2.11/web-fastopt.js
```

But I can't seem to load the file when I render the HTML using Scala Tags for the JVM project.

```
    "<!DOCTYPE html>" + html(lang := "en")(
      head(header)(
        script(`type` := "text/javascript", src:= "./target/scala-2.11/web-fastopt.js"),
      scalatags.Text.tags.body(body, footer)(optJs.map(js ⇒ onload := js.cmd))
    )
```

Does anyone know any working cross project examples I can reference?  The ones I found online can't actually run a local server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out there are 3 things wrong with the code above:

1. The compiled `fastopt.js` should be generated to the **resource** directory of the JVM project
2. The source should be `src:= "/web-fastopt.js"` instead
3. Finally, because I am using Akka HTTP for routing, I should add `getFromResourceDirectory("")` as the last route

This way the `fastopt.js` will loaded from the root url.